# Express route error "Err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, express

I have basic route for registering users fist it runs a stored procedure checking if the email exists within my SQL database and then runs a stored procedure updating the records if it does not.

However I keep getting the error

```
 Err:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

This is my route

```
app.post("/register", async (req, response) => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);
    const Email = req.body.email;
    const PasswordHash = req.body.password;
    const UserEmail = req.body.email;

    var request = new sql.Request();

    request.input("Email", sql.VarChar, Email);
    //request.input("Password", sql.VarChar, Password);

    const result = await request.execute("dbo.CheckEmailExists");

    if (result.recordsets[0].length > 0) {
      console.info("These credentials already exist");
      console.log(req.body);
    } else {
      console.info("these credentials do not exist well done");

      console.log({ UserEmail });
      request.input("UserEmail", sql.nVarChar, UserEmail);
      request.input("PasswordHash", sql.nVarChar, PasswordHash);
      request.execute("dbo.RegisterUser");

      console.log("done done");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Err: ", err);
    response.status(500).send("Check api console.log for the error");
  }
});
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix this ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RegisterUser]
  @UserEmail nvarchar(320),
  @PasswordHash nvarchar(100)

  AS

  INSERT into RegisteredUsers (Email,PasswordHash) values (@UserEmail,  HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @PasswordHash ))
```

Comment: As an aside, regardless of your error, this is actually not a good approach, because it's not safe under concurrency -- websites inherently allow parallel requests, meaning the e-mail could be added in between calls to your "exists" and "register" calls. You are typically better off with a transactionally consistent stored procedure that registers the user if they are not already registered, and returns the result.

Comment: Okay what a procedure like this look like ? As that was what I orginally tried but could not figure out how to implment it

Comment: That's probably food for a separate question. At the most basic level, something like `BEGIN TRANSACTION; SELECT @id = ID FROM [users] WITH (HOLDLOCK) WHERE ...; IF @id IS NULL BEGIN; INSERT ...; SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); COMMIT; SELECT @id`. Season with extra columns for the "was already registered" result to taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `sql.NVarChar` (N should be in Capitals).

Hope this helps!

Comment: it did something now it returns "(node:17420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Procedure or function RegisterUser has too many arguments specified."

Comment: Good, Can you now cross check the number of arguments that you've defined in your stored procedure against router code's arguments?

Comment: Hi I have updated the question this now contains my stored procedure

Comment: I cannot see the issue

Comment: your request has 3 parameters "Email" from checkemail, and later on two added UserEmail&PasswordHash for registeruser.

Comment: Yup!.. @lptr is spot on!

Comment: Okay I see. How would I make this valid ?

Comment: Either make your stored procedure to accept an extra parameter, Or cut-off the additional parameter which you have in your router code which you think that it is not required.

Comment: Better comment out `request.input("Email", sql.VarChar, Email);` in your router code, I don't see you using it your stored procedure.